# Problem to override Product/attribute/backend/Media

Tags: overrides, magento-1.9.3.3

I have a problem to override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media`.

Here is what I did:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Xx_Catalog>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Xx_Catalog>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <xx_catalog>
        <class>Xx_Catalog_Model</class>
      </xx_catalog>
      <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
          <product_attribute_backend_media>
        Xx_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media
          </product_attribute_backend_media>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

**Media.php**

```
class Xx_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media
{
  public function loadGallery($product, $object){
    echo "test";
    die();
  }
}
```

And here is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function loadGallery() on a non-object in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 51`

Do you know how to override this class?
I have Magento 1.9.3.3

Thanks

Comment: Someone? please ..

Answer (score 0):

Still no answer ...

I tried to change `catalog_resource` to `catalog_resource_eav_mysql4`, but I got the same error:

```
  <catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
    <rewrite>
      <product_attribute_backend_media>Xx_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
    </rewrite>
  </catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
```

Error is the same:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function loadGallery() on a non-object in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 51